# Input from readline owerwrites the prompt

Tags: bash, scripting, colors, read, readline

I'm trying to create an interactive bash script, where i can call given options from 1-n or just them like commands.

It will end up with a simulated prompt and 'read' is used to get the input, ofc.

But, if i type too big of a text, it will return to the beginning of the line and overwriting the prompt as i type.

Prompt is color coded and if i remove color escapes it will be just fine. But i like colors :)

Script prompt is like this:

```
NOC=$(echo -en '\033[0m')               # Default
RED=$(echo -en '\033[00;31m')
YELLOW=$(echo -en '\033[00;33m')
CYAN=$(echo -en '\033[00;36m')

OPROMPT="${RED}[Admin${CYAN}@${RED}bulletproof]#${NOC}"

until [ ! -z "$MCHOICE" ]; do
        read -p "${OPROMPT} " -e MCHOICE
done
```

What am i supposed to do to stop this behavior ? Cant seem to figure it out.
If i use echo or printf to display the prompt, it will erase it if i type something and then hit backspace to correct it.

If I'm not clear, here's an example:
This is the prompt (just picture it colored :P)

```
"[Admin@bulletproof]# "
```

...now here comes typing commands:

```
"[Admin@bulletproof]# vpn start my"
```

... now i continue typing

```
"domain.lanletproof]# vpn start my"
```

When it should be:

```
"[Admin@bulletproof]# vpn start mydomain.lan"
```

I also noticed that the buffer is different depending on the terminal window size. It doesn't start cutting off  at same point when i have the terminal maximized, but has longer "tolerance"

EDIT:
Just figured a way to substantially improve 'buffer' about this one.

If i set the code like this:

```
until [ ! -z "$MCHOICE" ]; do
        printf "$OPROMPT"
        read -p " " -e MCHOICE
done
```

It will allow me  to input a lot longer text... Don't know why..

Comment: All those color-changing escape sequences need to be enclosed with `\[` and `\]` so that bash knows they don't occupy any space on the screen.

Comment: I don't get it? How do i enclose them? I just tried

NOC=$(echo -en '\[\033[0m\]')         # Default
RED=$(echo -en '\[\033[00;31m\]')
YELLOW=$(echo -en '\[\033[00;33m\]')
CYAN=$(echo -en '\[\033[00;36m\]')

But still doesn't work. Or i should've tried something else?
I'm not talking about PS1 here, just trying to impersonate it

Comment: Still not doing it unfortunately. I've set NOC=$'\\[\e[0m\\]'
RED=$'\\[\e[00;31m\\]'
YELLOW=$'\\[\e[00;33m\\]'
CYAN=$'\\[\e[00;36m\\]'

OPROMPT="${RED}[Admin${CYAN}@${RED}bulletproof]#${NOC}"

read -p "$OPROMPT " -e MCHOICE

Bash version is 4.4.23 on Fedora 29.

Comment: The problem is the coloring. I think that Mark and Marco gave the right hints. Just try them.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't try this in a terminal window until this morning. I told you the wrong characters to use. Need to use `\001` and `\002` to surround the escape sequences in the `read` prompt. I've written up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading from a terminal, bash uses the `readline` library when executing the `read` builtin. It also uses readline when inputting command lines. In order to handle line wrapping correctly, readline needs to know if any characters in the prompt string do not take up any space on the screen.

If you were to call readline from C, you'd surround any escape sequence used to change screen colors with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> (`\001`) and <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> (`\002`).

Bash allows you to use `\[` and `\]` instead of those control characters when assigning to the command prompt variables (`PS1`, `PS2`, etc.). More recent versions of gdb support this, too.

Apparently bash doesn't allow this convenience for `read -p`. So you'll need to use those control characters.

```
NOC=$'\001\e[0m\002'               # Default
RED=$'\001\e[00;31m\002'
YELLOW=$'\001\e[00;33m\002'
CYAN=$'\001\e[00;36m\002'

OPROMPT="${RED}[Admin${CYAN}@${RED}bulletproof]#${NOC}"

until [ ! -z "$MCHOICE" ]; do
        read -p "${OPROMPT} " -e MCHOICE
done
```

Tested with bash 4.4.23.

Comment: Well, gotta say : hats off to you, sir ! :) worked like a charm, now even prompt stays displayed when i resize the terminal, before it would disappear every time i resize it !! :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I knew about the \[ thing (but only recently), but didn't know the \001 \002 characters